# React Native iOS app is crashing when receiving push notification and app is open

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, expo, react-native-ios, appdelegate

I can receive notifications when the app is closed / in the background so I know push is working, but when the app is open and it receives the notification, the app crashes with a "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".

It's an ejected expo app.

I have these methods in my app delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)token
{
    [super application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:token];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
{
    [super application:application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:err];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
    [super application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Comment: which npm library use for push notification?

Comment: React native one signal